# I have a radio button that changes the html content on my page but am having trouble making it work under one circumstance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the app in question:

http://codepen.io/illpill/pen/pPpWOZ

Where the code messes up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getsWeather('seattle, wa', 'f');
    $("#locSearchBtn").click(function() {
        getsWeather(document.getElementById('locSearch').value, 'f');
        return false;
    });
    $("#locSearchForm").submit(function() {
        getsWeather(document.getElementById('locSearch').value, 'f');
        return false;
    });
    $('input[type=radio][name=measurement]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'far') {
            getsWeather(document.getElementById('locSearch').value, 'f');
        } else if (this.value == 'cel') {
            getsWeather(document.getElementById('locSearch').value, 'c');
        }
    });
});
```

The radio buttons are supposed to change the temperatures from C to F. However, I coded it to run off of the value in the search bar but under the intitial view, there is no value in the search bar. How can I access the city inside the simpleweather framework and make this code work more efficiently? Also, extra points for helping me make this whole thing fade in and look smoother. I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I added .fadeIn() to many different places but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

To make the transition you can use:

```
.today{
      -webkit-transition: background-color 5000ms ease-out 1s;
      -moz-transition: background-color 5000ms ease-out 1s;
        -o-transition: background-color 5000ms ease-out 1s;
        transition: background-color 5000ms ease-out 1s;
}
```

And to insert a initial value onload you can use this in your HTML:

```
<body onload="insertvalue()">
```

Comment: This is okay but I was going for a solution that also loaded all of the information in a fading manner